# Error when trying to raise a discrete random variable to a negative power

Tags: r

```
library(discreteRV)

X <- RV(c(0, 9), c(1/2, 1/2))
X ** (-2)
```

whenever I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in RV(as.numeric(outcomes(X))^Y, probs(X), fractions = attr(X, "fractions"),  : 
  More probabilities/odds than outcomes provided
```

[Package is from GitHub: **discreteRV**](https://github.com/erichare/discreteRV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're trying to raise zero to a negative power, which essentially amounts to computing 1/0 (in this case, you're trying to find (1/0)^2) - an indeterminate form. When replacing `0` with `1` , the code runs fine

```
> X <- RV(c(1, 9), c(1/2, 1/2))
> X ** (-2)
Random variable with 2 outcomes

Outcomes 0.0123456790123457                  1
Probs                   1/2                1/2
```